# Did Anna Camp have any speaking lines in Pitch Perfect 2?

Tags: pitch-perfect-2

Anna Camp was a big part of Pitch Perfect; and she's listed in the credits of Pitch Perfect 2.

But I saw Pitch Perfect 2, and I can't recall seeing her at all!

So was she really in Pitch Perfect 2? And if so, where was she? Which scenes? Was she just under-utilized? Did Rebel Wilson steal all her lines? Or was she simply relegated to be just a pretty face in the Bellas lineup?

Comment: It looks like you didn't see the whole film

Comment: @Jim G: In the second half of the movie Anna camp was there if you have seen the whole movie.

Answer (score 4):

From [here](http://pitch-perfect.wikia.com/wiki/Aubrey_Posen):

> Aubrey Posen is a main character in the first Pitch Perfect film. She was the uptight and traditionalist co-leader of the Bellas. She is constantly critical and insists that The Bellas use the same set list the Bellas have been using for years. She is notorious for vomiting whenever she is under pressure. She is now a graduate of Barden University, thus making her no longer a Bella. **In the sequel, she is no longer a main character.** She now runs the Lodge of Fallen Leaves, where the Bellas visit in Pitch Perfect 2 to find their sound.
>
> She is a main character in the first film and a **supporting character in the sequel**. She is portrayed by actress Anna Camp.